# accessing CSV file in d3.js with no header row

Tags: javascript, python, csv, d3.js

I have a CSV file with data as such:

```
,tests,Mary,Joe,Frank
0,Test1,92,15,72
1,Test2,74,25,70
2,Test3,30,65,50
3,Test4,82,80,48
```

this data has been taken from a space delimited text file, converted into a dataframe in `pandas`, and then converted into a csv file for use in a `d3.js` driven scatterplot.

I want to bind data to points so each dot on that scatterplot would hold info like

```
studentname: Joe
Test1: 15
Test2: 25
Test3: 65
Test4: 80
```

for each student and each test. I have a function like

```
d3.csv('path/to/file.csv', function(error, data) {
    if error throw error;
    data.forEach(function(d) {
         d.studentname = d.name;
         d.test = d.tests;
         d.score = d.studentscore;
    })});
```

which I know doesn't access the data the way I want it to. How can I get the function to pick out the data I want correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your CSV will not work as you haven't got a name for the first element in the header.

If you did, and you read the first element of the dataset you will get something like :

```
randomname(this i made up) : 0
tests : Test1
mary : 92
joe : 15
frank : 72
```

So to get it in the format you want you will have to loop through this and make a new data set, something like so (bare in mind I converted this to JSON to work with in JSFiddle easily). There probably is easier ways too :

Create individual student objects :

```
var newData = [];

for (var i in data[0]) { //create individual student objects
  if (i != 'randomname' && i != 'tests') {
    newData.push({
      studentName: i 
    })
  }
}
```

Create array to get index of individual student. I did this to make it easier to retrieve the individual student objects to give them test data :

```
var elementPos = newData.map(function(x) {
    return x.studentName; //create array to get index of each student
  });
```

Now loop through the data, find each student and give them a test score :

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { //loop through data
  for (var j in data[i]) { //loop through each element in data[i]
    if (j != 'tests' && j != 'randomname') { //get all students test scores
      var thisStudent = newData[elementPos.indexOf(j)]; //get student object array based on index
      thisStudent["test" + i] = data[i][j]; //set testscore, incremented
    }
  }
}
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/h7b2p2eh/1/

Working code :

```js
var data = [{
  "randomname": 0,
  "tests": "Test1",
  "Mary": 92,
  "Joe": 15,
  "Frank": 72
}, {
  "randomname": 1,
  "tests": "Test2",
  "Mary": 74,
  "Joe": 25,
  "Frank": 70
}, {
  "randomname": 2,
  "tests": "Test3",
  "Mary": 30,
  "Joe": 65,
  "Frank": 50
}, {
  "randomname": 3,
  "tests": "Test4",
  "Mary": 82,
  "Joe": 80,
  "Frank": 48
}];

var newData = [];

for (var i in data[0]) { //create individual student objects
  if (i != 'randomname' && i != 'tests') {
    newData.push({
      studentName: i 
    })
  }
}


var elementPos = newData.map(function(x) {
    return x.studentName; //create array to get index of each student
  });

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { //loop through data
  for (var j in data[i]) { //loop through each element in data[i]
    if (j != 'tests' && j != 'randomname') { //get all students test scores
      var thisStudent = newData[elementPos.indexOf(j)]; //get student object array based on index
      thisStudent["test" + i] = data[i][j]; //set testscore
    }
  }
}



console.log(newData)
```